# Displaying large amounts of content on a page that we know people dont read

Tags: design, information-architecture

Due to compliance requirements I have to display essentially two large a4 sized pieces of copy within a single page on an already large web-form journey.

I've collected data on the current page and I know 94% of all users don't spend more than 15 seconds on the page. (It would take around 3-5 minutes to read this information, so we can assume people skim through it)

The issue i'm having is that I cant reduce this copy, i'm also not able to place it behind several pages or multi-pages. However i can try something similar to what Google have done on account creation which is allow for the content to sit within a max height container which the user can scroll through to read.

However when pitching this idea i've had conflicting opinions, as some people are concerned im hiding this information from customers and therefor creating a bad user experience and argue that it should be all displayed clearly - However we know this will result in a larger abandonment rate.

Anyone have alternative ideas or suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the content? Why this content should be displayed? Why user doesn't read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that displaying all that text on the page is creating the bad UX, and that hiding it is an improvement. But anyway. If my assumptions are correct, this is legalese that people have no desire to read, and little ability to understand. So here's a suggestion:

Show all of the text on the page. Move your form controls to the top of the page ("Continue" or "I Declare that I've Read This" or whatever gets users to the next step). If people are inclined to read it, it's all there, below. If they don't, they can easily move on.

Additionally, you could add a short, easily readable summary above the full text.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reduce the copy, but you can likely help interpret it. I've seen sites that break down large amounts of legal jargon into two columns: **one side shows the main points in casual terms, and the other shows the full legal details**.

This allows a user to skim the main points, get the gist of what the document says, but quickly dive into a section about which they may have concern.

[image: Two columns, with main points highlighted on the left, and details shown on the right]

Answer (score 0):

I assume js is not a big no no. 
First on desktop, you could show it in two columns(try that it all fits). Also show a floating action button which allows the user to Move to bottom.
In this case user can choose to read it or just move to bottom and move furthur, all within a few seconds.

Comment: Just to add to it, when showing it in two columns, put the page numbering on top.